Can we use runtime variables in conditional statement while calling a template in Azure Pipelines?
Hello I am not sure whether this could be achieved or not but heres my question ! I have two YAML files.

Parent Yaml : SetVariable.yml
Template Yaml : setvariabletemplate.yml

We are setting a Set Variable in parent variable and based on its value i.e. True/False. I want the following template to run.
Ideally : So if the value is false, it should go inside the template but if its true, it should fall in the else statement.
Result (whats happening now) : It is executing else statement irrespective of the Set Variable.
Below are the two YAMLs im using.

Parent Yaml

trigger: none

pool: Self Hosted Docker (Linux)

jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
    - powershell: |
        $a="lakshay"

        if ($a -eq "lakshay")
        {
          $skipEnvironmentDeployment = $true
        }
        else {
          $skipEnvironmentDeployment = $false
        } 
        
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SkipEnvironmentDeployment;isOutput=true]$skipEnvironmentDeployment"

      name: ProduceVar
    
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host $(ProduceVar.SkipEnvironmentDeployment)

- ${{ if eq(variables['ProduceVar.SkipEnvironmentDeployment'], 'false') }}:
  - template: setvariabletemplate.yml
  
- ${{ else }}:
  - job: C
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Output "Hello from Job C" 


Template Yaml

jobs:
- job: B
  steps:
    - powershell: Write-Host "Hello from Job B"

I looked at the documentation but couldnt find what I was looking for.

Short answer: No, you can't reference runtime variables at the point where templates are being expanded.

To turn a pipeline into a run, the first step is to expand templates and evaluate template expressions. But the output variable is only available at runtime, so setvariabletemplate.yml is not expanded. See the detailed info about pipeline run sequence from Process the pipeline.
According to your yaml, you seem to want to run job B when the value of SkipEnvironmentDeployment is false, otherwise run job C. If so, you can use runtime expressions $[] in the condition. Refer to the example below.
The Parent Yaml
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
    - powershell: |
        $a="lakshay"

        if ($a -eq "lakshay")
        {
          $skipEnvironmentDeployment = $true
        }
        else {
          $skipEnvironmentDeployment = $false
        } 
        
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SkipEnvironmentDeployment;isOutput=true]$skipEnvironmentDeployment"
      name: ProduceVar
    
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host $(ProduceVar.SkipEnvironmentDeployment)

- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  condition: eq(dependencies.A.outputs['ProduceVar.SkipEnvironmentDeployment'], 'false')
  steps:
  - template: mysetvariabletemplate.yml

- job: C
  dependsOn: A
  condition: eq(dependencies.A.outputs['ProduceVar.SkipEnvironmentDeployment'], 'true')
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Output "Hello from Job C" 

The Template Yaml:
steps:
  - powershell: Write-Host "Hello from Job B"


Update
If your jobA is also a template, you can put the dependsOn and condition inside the template.
The Parent Yaml:
jobs:
- template: jobA.yml
- template: jobB.yml
- template: jobC.yml

The jobA.yml:
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
    - powershell: |
        $a="lakshay1"

        if ($a -eq "lakshay")
        {
          $skipEnvironmentDeployment = $true
        }
        else {
          $skipEnvironmentDeployment = $false
        } 
        
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SkipEnvironmentDeployment;isOutput=true]$skipEnvironmentDeployment"
      name: ProduceVar
    
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host $(ProduceVar.SkipEnvironmentDeployment)

The jobB.yml:
jobs:
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  condition: eq(dependencies.A.outputs['ProduceVar.SkipEnvironmentDeployment'], 'false')
  steps:
    - powershell: Write-Host "Hello from Job B"

The jobC.yml:
jobs:
- job: C
  dependsOn: A
  condition: eq(dependencies.A.outputs['ProduceVar.SkipEnvironmentDeployment'], 'true')
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Output "Hello from Job C" 


Hi Ziyang thanks, but I cannot convert Jobs to Steps. In the actual code Job A is also inside a template and dependencies wouldnt work then.

@Lakshay Kashyap, you can put the dependsOn and condition inside the template. See my update above. In the above example, jobB/JobC will be expanded but will run based on the value of SkipEnvironmentDeployment.

Hey @Ziyang, thanks that will work. I didnt realise that adding a dependsOn will pause evaluation of the template.
